# Missing the CallSiteInformation when using NLog using the LoggerProvider through NLog.Web.AspNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

Missing the CallSiteInformation when using NLog using the LoggerProvider through NLog.Web.AspNetCore

I have a .NET Core application where I configure logging with Nlog through the NLog.Web.AspNetCore package:

```
public void ConfigureNLog(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Host.UseNLog();
}
```

But when trying to access call site information the respective data is not set on the `LogEventInfo`.

Comment: NLog will only capture callsite-information for the `LogEventInfo`, when requested by the NLog Target. Ex. NLog [TargetWithContext](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/T_NLog_Targets_TargetWithContext.htm) has the `IncludeCallSite`-property.